# How to handle slight deviation from Liskov substitution principle

Tags: c++, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

I landed in a situation where I need to derive from an existing class that represents a tcp packet, lets call it `PacketA`. It contains length of the packet name and name itself in it's header so there are methods in `PacketA` class that helps to retrieve name and name length.
Now I need to create another class let's call it `PacketB` which has identical properties as `PacketA` except it has no name and name length field. So I am thinking to derive `PacketB` from `PacketA` and override methods that have different behavior. Also plan is to throw an exception from methods that `PacketB` don't support, mainly name and name length.

This clearly don't follow Liskov substitution principle. Is there any way to implement this in cleaner way?

Comment: Extract stuff common to both PacketA and PacketB to a common base class? Or perhaps derive PacketA from PacketB?

Comment: Do you need to pass instances of `PacketB` to methods that expect `PacketA`? If _not_, then you should [prefer composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

Comment: @jaco0646 Yes I want to pass instances of PacketB to methods that expect PacketA. Basically I want to use run time polymorphism.

Comment: In that case I would set a default `name` for instances of `PacketB`. It could possibly even be an empty String.